# LilyPond: help to merge notes in different voices, \omit Stem and \omit Flag don't help

Tags: lilypond

I tried previously suggested solutions, and they didn't work. I am trying to merge noteheads to draw a melody guideline. In the code below I show them to demonstrate the effect, in the final version they will be hidden.

```
\version "2.24.3"
\language "italiano"

\score {
    \new PianoStaff <<
        \new Staff = "right" \relative do'' {
            <>
            \key re \minor
            \numericTimeSignature
            \time 3/4
            <<
                {
                    sold8-- (sol16 sold la4) r4
                    \oneVoice
                    <\single\override NoteHead.color = "firebrick" sib re mi sol sib>8-> [
                    <la dod mi sol la>->
                    <fad do' re fad>->]
                    <sol, do! sol'>16-- [(la' <fad, do' fad>8--)] r8
                }\\
                {
                    re'4~ 16 dod (mi sol la dod mi sol)
                }\\
                {
                    s2 s8 s16
                    \change Staff = "left"
                    \stemDown
                    %\hideNotes
                    la,
                    \showStaffSwitch
                    \once \omit Stem
                    \once \omit Flag
                    \change Staff = "right"
                    \once \override NoteHead.color = "seagreen"
                    sib8
                    \hideStaffSwitch
                    %\unHideNotes
                }
            >>
        }
        \new Staff = "left" \relative do {
            \key re \minor
            \clef bass
            <<
                {
                    fa4 (mi)
                }\\
                {
                    la,2
                }
            >>
            \clef treble
            dod'16 mi sol la
            <sol, re' mi sol>8_> [<la dod mi sol>_> \clef bass <re, la' re>_>]
            <la mib'>_- [<re, la' re>_- ] \clef treble
            la'''16 sib
        }
    >>
}
```

I highlighted not merged noteheads:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try ignoring note column collisions:

```
                %\hideNotes
                la,
                \showStaffSwitch
                \once \omit Stem
                \once \omit Flag
                \change Staff = "right"
                \once \override NoteHead.color = "seagreen"
                \override NoteColumn.ignore-collision = ##t % <-- new
                sib8
                \hideStaffSwitch
                %\unHideNotes
```

Since it's so usual to want to hide a single note head, I have this defined in global variables file:

```
hideNoteHead = \once {
  \omit Stem
  \omit Dots
  \omit Flag
  \hideNotes
  \override NoteColumn.ignore-collision = ##t
}
```

Then I can just write:

```
\hideNoteHead sib8
```

Comment: This is magic. Thanks!